# Why does this beginner Python string return 0?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with Python and am really confused as to why this piece of code returns '0' - I'd be grateful for any input on why this may not be working.

```
myString = [["1","a"], 0, [""]
        
In: myString[int(myString[0][0])]
Out: 0
```

Comment: That code doesn't parse. Missing bracket?

Comment: Try evaluating parts of the expression until you find a specific one you don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can trace your code like below:

```
>>> myString[0]
["1","a"]

>>> myString[0][0]
"1"

>>> int(myString[0][0])
1

>>> myString[1]
0
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason why is because `myString[0][0]` gives '1' and `int('1')` gives 1. `myString[1]` gives the element at position index 1, which is 0.